# Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: xbox360

Hey Guys I've Been Looking For An Answer To "Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" For Awhile Now Wondering if someone can help me solve this 
        IXboxConsole Jtag;

```
    private static uint HalSSMCM = Jtag.ResolveFunction("xboxkrnl.exe", 0x29); 
           // Line With The Problem ^

    public uint clientIndex;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to create some object of the class **Jtag** (Hoping Jtag will be the class having the method **ResolveFunction()**.

First create the instance and then access the method using the created instance object.